# Routing correctly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am learning Laravel 5.7.15.

I am trying to update data in Laravel. When I update client comment, I get MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

I have already looked at the other posts related to this error but still now get it fixed, please help me.

Laravel drives me crazy.

Here is my html

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/client_report/'.$id.'/edit', 'class' => 'form-horizontal group-border-dashed col-lg-6' ]) !!}
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group">
{{Form::text("Comment",$client->client_comments, array('id'=>'comment' 'class' => 'form-control', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder'=>'Client Comments')) }}
<p>{{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-space btn-success'}}</p>
</div>
```

and Route has

```
Route::get('/client_report/{id}/{edit}',function($id) {
    return view('clientEdit')
        ->with('id',$id);
})->middleware('auth');


Route::post('/client/submit/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'clientController@editClient']);
```

and Controller has

```
class clientController extends Controller {
function editClient(Request $request, $id) {
        $client = Client::find($id);
            $client->comment = $request->get('comment');
            $client->save();

    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting the wrong url.

In your html you are using

```
Form::open(['url' => '/client_report/'.$id.'/edit' ...
```

But your update route is

```
Route::post('/client/submit/{id}/edit' ...
```

Change the URL in your form, also make sure to make a **POST** request instead of **GET**.

Updating a resource should have PUT/PATCH route according to restful convention.

PS: current laravel version is 7.x, I would recommend you learn laravel 6.x at least, and HTML From Collectives (as far as I remember that's what they are called) are deprecated. You should not use deprecated tech.

Answer (score 0):

I think the url you're passing here is wrong.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/client_report/'.$id.'/edit', 'class' => 'form-horizontal group-border-dashed col-lg-6' ]) !!}
```

This above method is for edit, while you click on submit button it should redirect to `/client/submit/{id}/edit` this url.

Make you form url as below.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/client/submit/'.$id.'/edit', 'class' => 'form-horizontal group-border-dashed col-lg-6' ]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

**01. first change your router method to PUT**

```
Route::put('/client/submit/update/{id}', ['uses' => 'clientController@editClient']);
```

**02. change your form**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['clientController@editClient',  $id ],'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal group-border-dashed col-lg-6' ]) !!}
   {{Form::text("Comment",$client->client_comments, array('id'=>'comment' 'class' => 'form-control', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder'=>'Client Comments')) }}
   {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
   {{ Form::submit('submit', [ 'class' => 'btn btn-primary m-t-15 m-b-15'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the route to:

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], '/client/submit/{id}', 'clientController@editClient');
```

And the form to:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/client_report/'.$id, 'class' => 'form-horizontal group-border-dashed col-lg-6' ]) !!}
{{ csrf_field() }}
@method('PUT')

...
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing